# svn commands not working by using crontab

Tags: python, svn, cron

I am trying to schedule python script through crontab. Functionality of python script is svn cleanup and update commands. When i manually try python script, it is working as expected. Same script scheduled through crontab it is working but not getting proper result (result will be same as of last python script output, i.e when i manually run python script that will be output eventhough there are checkin's)

Below is python script:

```
subprocess.call("/usr/bin/svn cleanup "+path,shell=True)

subprocess.call("/usr/bin/svn update "+path,shell=True)

subprocess.call("/usr/bin/svn log --username usrname --password
pass1 "+path+">filename.txt",shell=True)
```

Below is command which is used in crontab,

- - - - - /usr/bin/python /path_to_script/filename.py

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any error log in logfile? Which user run the cron command (same as "you"?)?

Comment: No errors. But from crontab can see below logs,

(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output).

I am running crontab with normal user

Comment: Please include the error messages in your question, it will be helpful.